# css style whole element when hovering on its "after"

Tags: html, css

I have this button/speech bubble:

[image]

Code:

```
<div value="GO" id="go-div" class="bubble">
   <input type="submit" value="GO" id="go-button" style="    position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;" data-target="#search-results-page">
</div>
```

I have this styling, to change the little arrow colour, when hovering on the button:

```
#go-div.bubble:hover:after {
      border-color: transparent  #ffffff;
}
```

Which gives this effect when hovering over the bubble:

[image]

However, when I hover over the little arrow it doesn't cause the whole button to change color:

[image]

What is the css that selects the little arrow (`.bubble:after`) hover and effects the whole button (`.button`) to turn it white?

**Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3pbu7hj/1/)**

Comment: Please paste your css or better yet create a fiddle.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I just added the jsfiddle to the bottom of the question. Thanks

Comment: Remove #go-button:hover  to work as expected - https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/o3pbu7hj/2/

Comment: @NagaSaiA Your jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: check now @Beniamino_Baggins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your :hover style to the parent element and since :after is a child when you hover on the arrow it will trigger hover on parent.

```
#go-div:hover #go-button{
  background: white;
}
```

```css
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 65px;
padding: 0px;
background: #ff8282;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 0 15px 24px;
border-color: transparent #ff8282;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -15px;
right: -24px;
top: 50%;
}

#go-div.bubble:hover:after {
      border-color: transparent  #ffffff;
}

#go-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:white;
  color: brand-red
}

#go-button,
#go-div{
  font: 200 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff8282;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#go-div:hover #go-button{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div value="GO" id="go-div" class="bubble">
   <input type="submit" value="GO" id="go-button" style="    position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;" data-target="#search-results-page">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use **`.bubble:hover:after`** to select the entire bubble as shown below:

```
.bubble:hover:after .bubble {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

So, your only choice is to put the **`:hover`** on the parent element. This way both elements will be affected and no further action will be needed:

```
.bubble:hover > #go-button {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

You can check out an updated, working version of your jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o3pbu7hj/9/).

Comment: Glad to help @Beniamino_Baggins.